# Is there a way to try out Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-app-service-plans

I've looked at the Introductory Special Offer, but you still need to provide a credit card because when you go over your limits, you do have to pay. Man, I'm just a developer and I would like to try some things out with Azure Cloud. How can you evaluate a product if you can't try it out... Is there a way to get a sort of developer trial?

Comment: If you don't want to pay, don't go over your limits.

Comment: Did you try 4111111111111111 ?

Comment: Apparently Microsoft can also alter the conditions at any time they please... I think there really should be a sort of developers subscription with very limited possibilities. But that's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with your point. However if you want to just play around with the SDK for development, you could always use the Development Fabric locally.

Answer (score 2):

Q: How can you evaluate a product if you can't try it out

**Welcome to the "cloud"**

Use an open-source Platform-as-a-service setup. This way, you can test things on your own machines and migrate to a host if you like it. I dare say, using a freely available language (Python, Java) and running in something (GAE) that resembles a normal API is better. Hadoop might even be an alternative, and use something like Cloudera.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN Premium account holders get a special deal that provides quite a bit for free, and unless you try to launch a commercial site with it, I think you're going to have plenty of headroom:

- 3 1GB SQL Azure databases
- 7 GB in, 14 GB out monthly
- 750 hours (on a "small" compute instance)
- 1M access control transactions
- 5 service bus connections
- 10GB Azure storage + 1M storage transactions

I'd say that's pretty generous.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MSDN subscription, it comes with 750 hours of Azure.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Germany, you can try Windows Azure for 90 days. If you use Germany as your country, you can still use it. ([This account page](http://www.msdn-online.de/go/azureaccount) is in German.)