# Is there a way to try out Windows Azure for free?

Tags: .net, azure

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222332/is-there-a-way-to-try-out-windows-azure) but it's been asked over a year ago. Perhaps things have changed in this time span.

I'm mainly a **Windows Forms** developer with some dabbling in Ruby in my pet projects. I'd like to start poking around cloud based technology and see what things are like on the other side.

Thing is, since I'm a .NET developer I would feel **much** more comfortable using something in the Microsoft stack.

Is there some way for me to try out Azure and see what it's all about? I live in Bolivia so I don't have a credit card.

Comment: @jmeyer: does that let you try out Azure? I doubt that.

Comment: @jmeyer10: What does that have to do with Azure?

Comment: @Martino Fernandes: No, I'm suggesting not using Azure. That's why it isn't an answer.

Comment: Ouch, being in Bolivia precludes the use of credit cards?

Comment: I googled for "Windows Azure", then it took me here (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/) and I can see right in the main page "Try it free now!"

Comment: @jmeyer, MobileMe is not a competitor to Azure.  If you said AppEngine or EC2, that would at least be somewhat on topic.

Comment: @Martinho: Getting a credit card here is difficult and not as easy as it is Stateside. Over there I imagine all it takes is a signature. Here you have to prove income, home ownership, bills, co-signers, etc. Kind of difficult for a 21 year old father of two to pull off right now. :)

Comment: @Sergio, do any banks offer debit cards or [secured credit cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card#Secured_credit_cards)?  Probably, all that really matters is whether it has the right logo.  You may actually get better help at [money.stackexchange.com](http://money.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went to their site and they have a free trial link:

[Windows Azure Free Trial](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/free-trial/)

Nvm, just saw your credit card deal.

Comment: I'm sorry, on the ad on the right it says cloud power.

Comment: @jmeyer: MobileMe is a collection of online services and software (that just happen to be on the cloud). Azure is a development platform for cloud-based apps.